# How to update a component in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

My problem is that I want to change the color of the Avatar, I am using DrawNavigation nested with a Stack naviator, so when I click on the "Profile" option in the DrawNavigation it goes to the Profile screen where I can see several buttons with a different color , where if I click on one, the avatar would change color with respect to the color of the button, but the color of the Avatar does not change.

part of the DrawerNavigation code :

```
import React from "react"
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image} from "react-native"
import {DrawerContentScrollView, DrawerItemList} from "@react-navigation/drawer"
import AvatarC from "../components/AvatarC"

export default function UserContent({...props}){
    return(
        
        <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}  >
            
            <View style={styles.datUser}>
                <AvatarC size={60} color={'blue'}/>
                <View style={styles.Name}> 
                    <Title style={styles.Title} >Ryan Campbell</Title>
                    <Caption>ryan@gmail.com</Caption>
                </View>
            </View>
            <DrawerItemList {...props} />
        </DrawerContentScrollView>
    )
   }
```

part of Profile Code:

```
import React, {useState} from "react"
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, ScrollView,Dimensions, Image} from "react-native"
import {Avatar, DefaultTheme, } from "react-native-paper"
import AvatarC from "../components/AvatarC"



export default function Perfil(){
    const[color, setColor] = useState('blue')
    const changeColor = (newColor) =>{
        setColor(newColor)
    }
    return(
        <View style={{height:(screenHeight-200), flex:1}}>
            <ScrollView  showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} style={styles.viewBody} contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1}}>
                <View style={{ flex:1}}>
                    <AvatarC size={60} color={color}/>
                    <Text style={styles.changeColor}>
                        Change Color Profile:
                    </Text>
                    <View style={styles.viewColors}>
                    
                        <TouchableOpacity  onPress={()=>changeColor('red')} style={{...styles.bnColor, backgroundColor:"red"}}></TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity  onPress={()=>changeColor('green')} style={{...styles.bnColor, backgroundColor:"green"}}></TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity  onPress={()=>changeColor('yellow')} style={{...styles.bnColor, backgroundColor:"yellow"}}></TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity  onPress={()=>changeColor('blue')} style={{...styles.bnColor, backgroundColor:"blue"}}></TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity  onPress={()=>changeColor('pink')} style={{...styles.bnColor, backgroundColor:"pink"}}></TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity  onPress={()=>changeColor('purple')} style={{...styles.bnColor, backgroundColor:"purple"}}></TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity  onPress={()=>changeColor('orange')} style={{...styles.bnColor, backgroundColor:"orange"}}></TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity  onPress={()=>changeColor('brown')} style={{...styles.bnColor, backgroundColor:"brown"}}></TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity  onPress={()=>changeColor('black')} style={{...styles.bnColor, backgroundColor:"black"}}></TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity  onPress={()=>changeColor('#001269')} style={{...styles.bnColor, backgroundColor:"#001269"}}></TouchableOpacity>
                        
                    </View

                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Component Code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import {Avatar, DefaultTheme, } from "react-native-paper"

export default function AvatarC(props){
    const[color, setColor] = useState('blue')

    useEffect( () => {
        changeC()
    }, [props.color])
    const colorP = props.color
    
    var theme = {
        
        ...DefaultTheme,
        roundness: 2,
        colors: {
        ...DefaultTheme.colors,
        primary: color,
        },
    };
    const changeC =()=>{
        setColor(props.color)
    }
    return(
        <Avatar.Text

            size={props.size}
            label={"RC"}
            theme={theme}
        />
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must only focus on props in component

```
import {Avatar, DefaultTheme} from "react-native-paper"

export default function AvatarC(props){

var theme = {
    ...DefaultTheme,
    roundness: 2,
    colors: {
      primary: props.color,
    },
};

return(
    <Avatar.Text
        size={props.size}
        label={"RC"}
        theme={theme}
    />
)}
```